# Convolution - Massive spike in noise section

Tags: convolution

I am computing the correlation with MATLAB using the convolution fonction with a signal flipped before feeded into the function. Here are the results.

[image]

The first plot is the actual signal, the second one is the signal I am trying to find in the first signal and the third one is the convolution results. On the first plot, we can see at $n=3000$ and more  that the signal we are searching for is there and it is confirm by the spike in the third plot at $n = 3370$. However, there is massive spike in the beginning of the convolution (plot #3/ $n < 3000$) even if the beginning of the first signal is noise (plot #1/ $n < 3000$) . Why is there such spike in the convolution plot.

Comment: Please refer to **sample positions** such as n=70 or n=3000 etc, instead of saying right,left,beginning,end. It will make it much clearer about which spike you are referring to.

Comment: Did you **generated** these sequences? If yes, please put its code. That could be further clarifying. In addition, the **segment** of 3rd plot for $n<3000$ involves multiple **peaks** (or spikes as you refer to). I guess you feel all of them are erroneous ?

Comment: @Fat32 the first sequence is derive from a signal and the second sequence is the reference sequence generated in Matlab. The high noise come from the fact that it is the phase variation. Doing a derivation amplify noise.

Comment: So you **sampled** or **downloaded** the first sequence and, performed the rest in Matlab ? OK then.

Comment: The first sequence was sampled to recover I and Q data, than I compute and derive the phase in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

If your searched-for signal is partially similar to itself at some offset, that can also show up when correlated against an actual input signal containing it.

Test your searched-for signal by autocorrelation against itself to check for this problem.  If you want a sharp convolution peak against test input, you need a searched-for signal that has very low self-similarity at any lag.